# grouping static classes with the same behavior

Tags: c#

I have groups of logic that consist of static classes such as:

```
static class A {
    static int mutate(int i) { /**implementation*/ };
    static double prop(double a, double b) { /**implementation*/ }; 
}

static class B {
    static int mutate(int i) { /**implementation*/ };
    static double prop(double a, double b) { /**implementation*/ }; 
}
```

In this case, A and B are static classes that implement the same behavior via a group of functions (e.g. mutate). I would like to use something like an interface for this pattern, however since static classes cannot implement interfaces I am not sure what to do. What is the best way to implement this type of behavior cleanly?

EDIT:

Here is an example of what I am currently doing. The classes have no state so normally I would make them static.

```
Interface IMutator {
    int mutate(int i);
}

class A : IMutator {
    int mutate(int i) { /**implementation*/ };
}

class B : IMutator {
    int mutate(int i) { /**implementation*/ };
}

class C {
    public List<IMutator> Mutators;
    public C(List<IMutator> mutators) { 
        Mutators = mutators;
    }
}

//Somewhere else...
//The new keyword for A and B is what really bothers me in this case.
var Cinstance = new C(new List<IMutator>() {new A(), new B() /**...*/});
```

Comment: Why can't you use non-static classes and interfaces? Is there any reason you are going for static? What is the usage of these classes?

Comment: There is no data in these classes. There is purely groups of functions, so it seems strange to make them non-static, as each instance would be identical. However, this is my current approach.

Comment: Can you provide a sample usage of these classes? How many of similar classes will you have? Just these 2, dozens, hundreds? It is hard to suggest an alternative when the context is not clear

Comment: Wrap your static classes functionality with a normal class that implement a interface.

Comment: Perhaps a dumb questions, but why not delete the duplicates and just use one class if they are the same, as per your example?

Comment: The function types are the same but the implementations will differ in each class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stateless class doesn't have to be static. 
Moreover, static dependencies isn't a good choice, when you want to write unit tests, or when you want to extract some common interface (as in your case).

It's OK to have non-static classes, containing logic only. E.g., people build ASP .NET applications using stateless controllers.

So, just throw away `static` and extract an interface.

Comment: Please see my EDIT. Is this what you meant? Thanks.

Comment: @shell: yes, that's what I meant. You can use DI container to inject `IMutator` implementations inside `C` instances (it's about your bothering). Is this some sort of plugin-based application?

Comment: I'm new to C#, thanks for the help. I will look at DI. Much appreciated.

Comment: @shell: you're welcome. Here's a number of links to start reading: Ninject: http://www.ninject.org/ Autofac: https://autofac.org/ MEF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Apart from @Dennis answer (*which I have +1'ed, and it's indeed the way to go*), other approach that may work, is having a set of functions (`Func<>`) and/or actions (`Action<>`) and resolve them using reflection. The code would not be specially elegant nor performant, but it works.

I've made a quick example [on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SX8j39)